# Как конвертировать EXCEL в PDF в java?

Tags: java, excel, pdf

Есть ли простой способ конвертировать excel документы (различного размера), в pdf файл, без каких либо изменений по внешнему виду?

Comment: Есть. Отправить печать на pdf  принтер.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Aspose.Cells для Java для конвертации допустим XLSX файл в PDF с помощью пару строчек кода.

Ниже пример:

```
// Load your XLSX file in Workbook object
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("C:\\TempDir\\YourExcel.xlsx");

// Save the document in PDF format
workbook.save("C:\\TempDir\\Output.pdf", SaveFormat.PDF);
```

Больше есть тут: https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsjava/Converting+Workbook+to+Different+Formats#ConvertingWorkbooktoDifferentFormats-ConvertingExceltoPDFFiles

Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Я думаю, стоит упомянуть, что Aspose.Cells - платный продукт, обзорная версия работает 30 дней.